# Performance cost of using Partials in Razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I like using partials in my Razor views. It makes the code nice and clean. But is there any significant performance cost of using partials? I've created a simple test. It shows that using partials is **much** slower.

test.cshtml:

```
@{
   var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); 
   stopwatch.Start();         
   for(var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
      var str = "my string #" + i;        
      @Html.Partial("_MyPartial",str)  // replace with @str on second test
      <br />        
   }
   stopwatch.Stop();
   <br />
   @: Time elapsed (ms): @(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)
}
```

_MyPartial.cshtml:

```
@Model
```

The code with the partial executed in 340ms, while the inline @str code was showing 0 or 1 ms.  It is really shocking for me because it means I should get rid of all my cute partials, at least of those in loops.

If anyone wants to confirm or criticize my experiment, you are very welcome.

Comment: Why are you concerned? Are you not meeting your performance requirements? Or is this purely an expirement? If that's the case, yes there is a performance penalty for using partials.

Comment: I had a page with customers tables where I used a partial to display some funky html for each customer. I needed to be the the output as quick as possible - that's why I decided to make a test. Also, replaceing Html.ActionLink helped to improve the rendering speed a lot. After all optimization - I got about 10x speed increase for this particular page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Make sure you are not running your site in debug mode and that the MVC project is getting compiled in the release configuration. Running a site in debug mode makes MVC skip a bunch of caching
2. You did not provide your baseline code so it's hard to determine if your conclusions are justified.
3. Do you think that having a 1000 calls to Partial is common? Seems like you are measuring a scenario that's not realistic. In any reasonably complex website the cost of database calls will usually dwarf any of the view code.
4. Please watch this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Steven-Smith-Improving-ASPNET-MVC-Application-Performance

Comment: Thank you, good points. Yes, I tested in release mode and just set 1000 for the test only purposes. I agree with you, on my real page there are only 50 loop iterations but it still makes a big difference when I use inline html.

Answer (score 2):

In this operation you've got a stopwatch that's going through a loop 1000 times, and accessing that partial. That partial is in a separate memory location, and may even require disk i/o access to load. It's clearly inferior to putting that code on the page itself.

But don't reject the partials everywhere. If you are in a situation where you don't have code that's loaded multiple times on the page (unlike this code you've showed), then partials are pretty useful, and the performance penalty they inflict isn't so severe that you should be troubled.

Comment: Agreed, I certainly will not stop using partial in non-loop situations. It's such a handy feature - sometimes it's more important to have a clean and maintainable code than win a 10ms.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, using partials does inflict a performance penalty; a new file has to be opened and read, and IO is always slow/expensive.

Comment: Downvote because you state the obvious without checking/knowing how MVC handles partials. Your answer does not take caching into account which is the determining factor here since the OP asks for repeatedly calling the same partial view.